# Repeatedly displaying random-noise images using NumPy and PyQt4

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, scipy

I'm having trouble using a QTimer to repeatedly

1. generate a height-by-width-by-3 numpy array
2. convert the numpy array to a Qt-friendly image, and
3. display the image in the main Qt window

(Eventually the images won't be random.)

Here is the relevant code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc.pilutil import toimage
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt

def nparrayToQPixmap(arrayImage):
    pilImage = toimage(arrayImage)
    qtImage = ImageQt(pilImage)
    qImage = QtGui.QImage(qtImage)
    qPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qImage)
    return qPixmap

class DetectionWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DetectionWidget, self).__init__()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):

        self.setFixedSize(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT)

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)

        self.timer.start(1000)

    def onTimeout(self):

        npImage = np.random.rand(self.HEIGHT, self.WIDTH, 3)
        qPixmap = nparrayToQPixmap(npImage)
        self.label.setPixmap(qPixmap)
```

This displays the FIRST image, but Python segmentation faults on the second iteration at `self.label.setPixmap(qPixmap)`. Also, it segmentation faults even if I DON'T update the label but instead save the image using `qPixmap.save(...)`, which makes me think that the resulting qPixmap is somehow corrupt after the first iteration.

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be because of a bug in the `QImage` to `QPixmap` conversion. The code works as long as the `QImage` is in the right format..

```
qImage = QtGui.QImage(qtImage)
```

becomes

```
qImage = QtGui.QImage(qtImage).convertToFormat(QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
```